# Is there a name for a "hierachical" graph "inferred" from the edges and vertices of another graph?

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, terminology

First of all, I'm very sorry about the title of this question, but I don't know how else to word it.

The type of graph I'm looking at is one that defines its edges and vertices based on a different graph.

I'll start with a practical example that's closely related to what I'm working on. Consider the counties of England. Most counties share a border with another county. These counties can also be grouped into regions; Greater Manchester is in the North West, Nottinghamshire is in the East Midlands, etc. Most of these regions share a border with another region. However, asking "Which regions border the region I'm looking at" is the same as asking "Which regions have counties that border a county in the region I'm looking at".

I hope that illustrates how the relationships between regions can be "inferred" by the relationships between counties. So if I was to sketch this out more formally:

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a directed graph. Define a surjection $\operatorname{Category} : V \rightarrow C$ where $C$ is a non-empty set. It cannot be said in general that $V$ and $C$ are related in any way other than through $\operatorname{Category}$. Then the graph $G_C = (V_C, E_C)$ exists such that:

- $V_C = \{\ \operatorname{Category}(v)\ |\ v \in V \ \}$
- $E_C = \{\ (\operatorname{Category}(v_1), \operatorname{Category}(v_2))\ |\ (v_1, v_2) \in E \ \}$

Is there a name for $G_C$? Is there anything interesting about the relationship between $G$ and $G_C$?

***Note**: I define $G$ to be a directed graph, but I assume that the definition given above can be trivially applied to undirected graphs. I would be interested to know if there's any difference in whether $G_C$ is inferred from a directed or undirected graph.*

Comment: Graph Theory is not my area, but I think you might want the concept of a [quotient graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_graph).

Comment: @MarkS. I think it is! Thanks very much. Would you like to write you comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: This is almost a block graph (except in block graphs, the "categories" are blocks--which have a particular definition).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [a basic theorem about equivalence relations and projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Projection), a surjective function like "$\mathrm{Category}$" makes a canonical bijection between $C$ and the equivalence classes of the [equivalence kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Equivalence_kernel) of the function. In other words, $\mathrm{Category}$ gives rise to a relevant equivalence relation on $V$.

Given such an equivalence relation (which you [may interpret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Fundamental_theorem_of_equivalence_relations) as a partition of the vertices into "categories"), then defining the new vertices and edges via your definitions of $V_C$ and $E_C$ is exactly what is done in defining the [**quotient graph**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_graph) corresponding to that equivalence relation.